# Heroku Nodejs get image 404

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm using MEAN Stack(express and nodejs) to deploy my project into heroku. I'm using a sandbox database provided by mongolab(mlab) addons. My question is why does the the image file cannot be displayed after a certain period of time(after 30-40 minutes)? The system has no problem when reloading. The image will still be there. But after the period mentioned, the server cannot Get the image and return 404 error. Here's an example: 
[image]

Comment: So the image is displayed before 30-40 minutes ? Have you checked the log messages ?

Comment: How are the images being stored/retrieved? Are you using some sort of service for this or using the database? If within the database, is there any reason to believe the data could be removed in the time period? Are you receiving any errors when rendering the data for the response? This and of course any relevant code to those points really need to be part of your question.

Comment: @NeilLunn I'm using mongodb for my database. Yes I'm using service to post and get data. The data is return in the form of an array and has objects in it that carries data such as Strings, Date and Number. All the data successfully retrieved except for image. If my code have errors, it will show at the first time I run it. This mean that after certain period of time my image data is being corrupted or deleted in mongolab and I wanna know why and how to solve it. Here's my code if u insist: https://plnkr.co/edit/gF6zsBgCoKYGxL3QzXdJ?p=catalogue
Note that I've delete some unnecessary code.